# MongoDB match criteria in aggregate acting unexpectedly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently working with a collections with documents like this

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5aa8665dcfe5305814e6dd90"
    },
    "userID": "5aa71af7b562de0c690eb6e0",
    "rebate": 64,
    "status": "approved"
}
```

The query I am running is as follows:

```
var id = "5aa71af7b562de0c690eb6e0";

Warranty.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $match: {
                "userID": id,
                "status": "approved"
            }
       },
       {
           $group: {
               "_id": null,
               "total": {
                   $sum: "$rebate"
               }
          }
      }
    ], function(err, sum) {

        if (err) throw err;

        res.send(sum);

});
```

Currently, this is returning `[]`

The expected result is `[ { "_id": null, "total": 64 } ]`

I have also attempted to cast the variable id to ObjectId like so:

`"userID": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)` and the result is still an empty array.

The interesting thing is if I remove the match "userID" line this works and returns `[ { "_id": null, "total": 64 } ]` but I need this to limit the query to the active user only.

I am new to Mongo aggregate.

### Possible solution

For some reason doing this `"userID": id + '',` fixes the issue.  I don't really understand why; would anyone explain to me why this is the case? I would assume since the id is comprised of alpha-numeric characters that it would already be a string, right?

Comment: What is your match stage returning? Cast userid to objectid

Comment: how is id value prepared ? Try `"userID": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)`

Comment: Is is a String passed from the front end. It is there as I have logged it just prior to the code above.

Comment: yes cast string to objectid before sending to aggregation like I described above

Comment: Adding mongoose.Types.ObjectId still returns a blank array

Comment: Match by itself is returning a blank array. If I remove the userID line then it returns all objects with the status of “approved” as expected.

Comment: did you try `{
            $match: {
                "userID": mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id),
                "status": "approved"
            }
       }` ?

Comment: Yes @Veeram it returned an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id needed to be converted to a string for some reason.  I do not understand why this is the case but simply adding  `"userID": id + ''` made the query run as expected.